# How can I get more information on Python unexpected SIGABRT?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, sigabrt

I'm using:

1. MacOS Catalina, version 10.15 (19A603).
2. python 3.7.4
3. pip3

Running and Debugging the following Python code within venv:

```
import jose
print(jose)
from jose import jwt
token = jwt.encode({'key': 'value'}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
print(token)
```

results with the following error:

**Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)**

the specific line is: from jose import jwt.

How can I get more information towards solving that problem.

My pip freeze of venv:

```
Active-Alchemy==1.0.0
alembic==1.2.1
aniso8601==8.0.0
anyjson==0.3.3
appnope==0.1.0
arrow==0.15.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
attrdict==2.0.0
attrs==19.3.0
auth0-python==3.1.2
backcall==0.1.0
bcrypt==3.1.7
beautifulsoup4==4.8.1
bleach==3.1.0
boto3==1.10.2
botocore==1.13.2
cachetools==3.1.1
certifi==2019.9.11
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
configparser==4.0.2
crypto==1.4.1
cryptography==2.4.2
cssselect==1.1.0
cytoolz==0.9.0.1
decorator==4.3.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
django-dotenv==1.4.2
dnspython==1.16.0
docutils==0.15.2
EasyProcess==0.2.7
ecdsa==0.13
emoji==0.4.5
entrypoints==0.3
eth-abi==1.2.2
eth-account==0.3.0
eth-hash==0.2.0
eth-keyfile==0.5.1
eth-keys==0.2.0b3
eth-rlp==0.1.2
eth-typing==1.3.0
eth-utils==1.2.2
eventlet==0.25.1
facebook-sdk==2.0.0
feedparser==5.2.1
Flask==1.1.1
flask-restplus==0.13.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
forex-python==1.5
future==0.16.0
gevent==1.4.0
google-api-python-client==1.6.3
google-auth==1.6.3
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
greenlet==0.4.15
gunicorn==19.9.0
hexbytes==0.1.0
httplib2==0.10.3
idna==2.5
importlib-metadata==0.23
inflection==0.3.1
ipykernel==5.1.3
ipython==7.8.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
iso3166==0.8
iso8601==0.1.12
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jedi==0.15.1
Jinja2==2.10.3
jmespath==0.9.4
joblib==0.14.0
jsonpickle==0.9.5
jsonrpclib==0.1.7
jsonschema==3.1.1
jupyter-client==5.3.4
jupyter-core==4.6.1
logstash-formatter==0.5.17
lru-dict==1.1.6
lxml==4.4.1
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.0
mistune==0.8.4
monotonic==1.5
more-itertools==7.2.0
mysqlclient==1.4.4
Naked==0.1.31
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbformat==4.4.0
nltk==3.4.5
notebook==6.0.1
numpy==1.17.3
oauth2client==4.1.2
orderedset==2.0.1
Paginator==0.5.1
pandas==0.25.2
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parsimonious==0.8.1
parso==0.5.1
passlib==1.7.1
pexpect==4.7.0
pg8000==1.10.2
pickleshare==0.7.5
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==2.0.10
psycopg2==2.7.3
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
ptyprocess==0.6.0
py==1.7.0
py4j==0.10.8.1
pyasn1==0.3.3
pyasn1-modules==0.1.1
pycountry==19.8.18
pycparser==2.19
pycryptodome==3.7.0
Pygments==2.4.2
PyJWT==1.6.1
PyMySQL==0.6.6
Pyro4==4.77
pyrsistent==0.15.4
pyscreenshot==0.5.1
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-editor==1.0.3
python-jose==3.0.1
python-logstash==0.4.6
pytz==2017.2
PyVirtualDisplay==0.2.4
PyYAML==3.13
pyzmq==18.1.0
qgrid==1.1.1
redis==3.3.11
requests==2.22.0
requests-file==1.4.2
retry==0.9.2
retrying==1.3.3
rlp==1.0.3
rq==1.1.0
rsa==4.0
s3transfer==0.2.1
scrypt==0.8.6
Send2Trash==1.5.0
sentry-sdk==0.13.0
serpent==1.28
shellescape==3.4.1
simplejson==3.11.1
six==1.12.0
snowplow-analytics-sdk==0.2.3
soupsieve==1.9.4
SQLAlchemy==1.2.14
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.34.2
sqlitedict==1.6.0
statsd==3.3.0
terminado==0.8.2
testpath==0.4.2
textblob==0.15.3
tldextract==2.1.0
toolz==0.9.0
tornado==6.0.3
tqdm==4.36.1
traitlets==4.3.3
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.21.1
wcwidth==0.1.7
web3==4.8.1
webencodings==0.5.1
websockets==6.0
Werkzeug==0.16.0
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
zipp==0.6.0
```

HOW DID I SOLVED IT:

Wrote a script that installed dependencies one by one, then, execute the Python code to catch what dep leads to failure.

Discovered it starts to throw after **asn1crpto** installed.

Tried to install only **asn1cyrpto** and **jose** -> Python code executed successfully.

Then, re-run the script that installs deps one by one with jose and asn1crypto already installed, found out that after **cryptography** dep installed it starting to throw again

So searched for (**cryptography** + **asn1crypto**) related issues.

Found a suggestion to update **asn1crypto** 0.24.0 -> 1.0.0

Issue solved.

Comment: SIGABRT smells like a library compatibility or dependency problem or something. Do you have access to another box you could try setting up your venv on? Or maybe try through Docker?

Comment: It probably is the issue. How can I gather more information on current setup in order to fix it?

Comment: I'd probably try as stripped down a venv as you can get first (so just `jose` and its autoinstalled dependencies). If that crashes still, then you can start looking more into what system libraries its using and maybe try different versions of those.

Comment: I installed only python-jose and it's working. Then I split the req.txt to chunks install and saw if it still running fine.

Reached asn1crypto. When I installed that lib the program started to crash again.

Recreate the environment and installed only python-jose and asn1crypto and it works but when I'm installing the rest of the deps it failed.

How can I find what is the combination that causes it?

Comment: This is possibly an issue with older versions of asn1crypto importing a (potentially) different OpenSSL than the cryptography package does. The latest cryptography no longer depends on asn1crypto (and the latest asn1crypto no longer does this) so upgrading either of them might resolve the issue.

Comment: @PaulKehrer exactly. Found that reason eventually after writing a script to install the dependecies one by one. Discovered that asn1crpto, cryptography, and Jose are causing the crash. Then, update asn1crpyto to version 1.0.0 and it worked.

Comment: The most precise method is to examine the coredump (dumping core must be enabled on some systems). The stack trace might give some clue. However, this low level stuff requires lots of patience and dedication to dive quite deeply into the problem in general.

Answer (score 7):

I was having similar problem when using pyjwt, Even using `pyjwt -v` will fail with `SIGABRT`. Try upgrading cryptography version (from cryptography==2.4.2) to version listed below, it fixed problem for me.

```
"cryptography": {
    "version": "2.8"
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The module faulthandler dump Python tracebacks explicitly, on a signal :

```
python -X faulthandler test.py
```

Comment: A lifesaver! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would try wrapping the offending line in a try/except block, and logging the exception.

Comment: Added try and except and it doesn't give me more information. sama unexpected SIGABRT

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, and [aky08](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58618711/5050932) was right. Upgrade `cryptography` to `2.8` solve it.